# How can I grab the user inputs and print the letter count of each word he/she typed?

Tags: python, user-input

This is what I have so far and I'm stuck.

```
user_input = float(input('Welcome to the Amazing Word Program; how many words will you enter?'))

my_list=[]
word = input('Enter word:')

while word != '':
    my_list.append(word)
    word = input('Enter word:')
```

The point of my code is to use while loops. We are supposed to print an end result of the users entered words and the letter count of each word.

Here is the result of my program:

```
Welcome to the Amazing Word Program; how many words will you enter? 4
Enter word: apple
Enter word: orange
Enter word: strawberries
Enter word: kiwi
Enter word:
```

After the user entered 4 words, what is also supposed to print out is the letter count of each word.

Here is a complete example:

```
Welcome to the Amazing Word Program How many words will you enter? 4 Enter word: Python
Enter word: used
Enter word: for
Enter word: programming

Word: Python Length: 6
Word: Python Length: 4
Word: Python Length: 3
Word: Python Length: 11
```

I'm a first year college student and at the moment, while loops do seem difficult, so I apologize if this seems like an easy code to write.

How can I use while loops to print out the length of each word, no matter how many words the user entered?

**PYTHON**

Comment: Why do you use `float`?  instead of `int` ?   For a line with multiple words - thinking to `split()` first then count the letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print out your input. Also you don't actually need to save your words to a list unless you are doing something with the list afterwards. In this case you are just printing the input so you can just remove the list operations entirely.

As for the length, Python has a 'len()' function that returns the length of a given input.

```
print('Welcome to the Amazing Word Program')

word = input('Enter word:')

while word != '':
    print("Word:", word, "Length:", len(word))
    word = input('Enter word:')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of a string like this:

```
some_string = "hello world"

print(len(some_string))
```

And when you can stop a while loop like this:

```
number = 0
while number <= 4:
    # do some work
    number += 1 # increment number
```

And the while loop automatically stop when `number` hit 5.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want the code to print the length of each word after user entered all the words... To do it we first need to capture the length of the "my_list" list, we do it by creating an int and setting the value of the length:

```
listLen = len(my_list)
```

Then we need to create another int and set its value to 0 (We will use this one to count the number of words's length to print and print words in order)

```
listNum = 0
```

Now we create an while loop that wont stop until listNum equals to listLen value, to do it we will first print the word length in ascending order:

```
while listNum != listLen:
  #While listNum (0) is not equal to listLen (number of words entered), it will loop again
  print( "Word", listNum, "length is:", len(my_list[listNum]) ) #Will print the length of the word number X (where X is the value of listNum that will be incremented 1 by 1 so we can print the length of each word 1 by 1 in ascending order)
  listNum += 1 #will increment 1 more value to the listNum, so the next loop will print the next word's length
```